# about the prosses of ( if and esle if function )

Tags: javascript

For example I have this code

```
if ( false ) 
{
    // 1000 lines of code
} else if {
    // 1000 lines of code
} else {
    code(true)
}
```

I wanted to know that when this code is run, if the values for both `if` and `else if` were false, the machine immediately runs `else` logic, or the both of the code (1000 line code) underneath `if` and `else if` would be read first and take time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language parsing is a complex business, and explaining that to someone takes a University module, not a Stack Overflow answer.

But in brief, I can say this:

- the block that isn't executed must still be parsed and interpreted
- however, it will not be executed. Its variables won't be declared or given values, and its function calls will not happen.

Comment: You implicitly gave an answer why the whole script has to be parsed before it can be run: Variables and function may be declared after the point of use.

Comment: @Kay: It's even simpler than that: if the block is not parsed, the interpreter won't know where it ends.